# How to fix "identifier of an instance of class was altered from id to null" (Java)

Tags: java, spring-boot

Sometimes I got the problems in my Web Application Project. When I try to update Construction Member entity , and the Id of Construction Order was changed from old value to null.

Meanwhile, Table “Construction Member” does not have a Foreign key with “Construction Order”, only Construction Team has Foreign key with “Construction Order”

*(“ConstructionOrder” > “Construction Team” > “Construction Member”)*

Although I do not call any method to update “Construction Order”, I just work with data of “Construction Member” and I was also used "updatable=false" for every @ManyToOne of these Entities to avoid unnecessary data changes. But the error still appears.

Note: When I try to restart the server, the error does not exist and while I manipulate a lot of data on my web-application, the error appears again, which forces me to restart the server again to continue using Web App.

**- Here is my Error**

```
c.l.n.c.ConstructionMemberController.update - Error when updating constructionMember.
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: identifier of an instance of com.logsik.nguyencons.domain.ConstructionOrder was altered from 1 to null; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.logsik.nguyencons.domain.ConstructionOrder was altered from 1 to null
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.logsik.nguyencons.controller.ConstructionMemberController.update(ConstructionMemberController.java:55)
    at com.logsik.nguyencons.controller.ConstructionMemberController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8b6ed292.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.logsik.nguyencons.controller.ConstructionMemberController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$63c589cb.update(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at com.logsik.nguyencons.config.SimpleCorsFilter.doFilter(SimpleCorsFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.logsik.nguyencons.domain.ConstructionOrder was altered from 1 to null
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 128 common frames omitted
```

**- Here my database.**

Construction Member

```
CREATE TABLE `construction_member` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`construction_team_id` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`work_on` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`note` longtext NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_constructionMember_constructionTeam` FOREIGN KEY (`construction_team_id`) REFERENCES `nguyencons`.`construction_team` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
INDEX `fk_constructionMember_constructionTeam` (`construction_team_id` ASC) USING BTREE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 0
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
KEY_BLOCK_SIZE = 0
MAX_ROWS = 0
MIN_ROWS = 0
ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic
STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES = 0;
```

Construction Team

```
CREATE TABLE `construction_team` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`construction_order_id` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`team_name` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`note` longtext NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_constructionTeam_constructionOrder` FOREIGN KEY (`construction_order_id`) REFERENCES `nguyencons`.`construction_order` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
INDEX `fk_constructionTeam_constructionOrder` (`construction_order_id` ASC) USING BTREE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 0
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
KEY_BLOCK_SIZE = 0
MAX_ROWS = 0
MIN_ROWS = 0
ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic
STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES = 0;
```

Construction Order

```
CREATE TABLE `construction_order` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`project_location_id` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`start_work_date` date NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`end_work_date` date NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`number_of_completed_day` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`status` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`note` longtext NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_constructionOrder_projectLocation` FOREIGN KEY (`project_location_id`) REFERENCES `nguyencons`.`project_location` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
INDEX `fk_constructionOrder_projectLocation` (`project_location_id` ASC) USING BTREE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 0
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
KEY_BLOCK_SIZE = 0
MAX_ROWS = 0
MIN_ROWS = 0
ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic
STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES = 0;
```

**- Here is my Domain**

Construction Order.

```
@Entity(name="construction_order")
public class ConstructionOrder implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
 private Long id;


 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name= "project_location_id", updatable=false)
 private ProjectLocation projectLocation;



 @Column
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 private Date startWorkDate;

 @Column
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 private Date endWorkDate;

 @Column
 private Integer numberOfCompletedDay;

 @Column
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 private ConstructionOrderStatus status;

 @Lob 
 @Column(columnDefinition="longtext")
 private String note;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ProjectLocation getProjectLocation() {
    return projectLocation;
}

public void setProjectLocation(ProjectLocation projectLocation) {
    this.projectLocation = projectLocation;
}

public Date getStartWorkDate() {
    return startWorkDate;
}

public void setStartWorkDate(Date startWorkDate) {
    this.startWorkDate = startWorkDate;
}

public Date getEndWorkDate() {
    return endWorkDate;
}

public void setEndWorkDate(Date endWorkDate) {
    this.endWorkDate = endWorkDate;
}

public Integer getNumberOfCompletedDay() {
    return numberOfCompletedDay;
}

public void setNumberOfCompletedDay(Integer numberOfCompletedDay) {
    this.numberOfCompletedDay = numberOfCompletedDay;
}

public ConstructionOrderStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(ConstructionOrderStatus status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getNote() {
    return note;
}

public void setNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
}




}
```

Construction Team

```
@Entity(name = "construction_team")
public class ConstructionTeam implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "construction_order_id" , updatable = false)
    private ConstructionOrder constructionOrder;

    @Column
    private String teamName;

    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "longtext")
    private String note;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ConstructionOrder getConstructionOrder() {
        return constructionOrder;
    }

    public void setConstructionOrder(ConstructionOrder constructionOrder) {
        this.constructionOrder = constructionOrder;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

}
```

Construction Member

```
@Entity(name = "construction_member")
public class ConstructionMember implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable=false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "construction_team_id", updatable=false)
    private ConstructionTeam constructionTeam;

    @Column
    private String workOn;

    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "longtext")
    private String note;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public ConstructionTeam getConstructionTeam() {
        return constructionTeam;
    }

    public void setConstructionTeam(ConstructionTeam constructionTeam) {
        this.constructionTeam = constructionTeam;
    }

    public String getWorkOn() {
        return workOn;
    }

    public void setWorkOn(String workOn) {
        this.workOn = workOn;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

}
```

**- Here Is My Construction Memeber Controller ¬¬ (Update)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/constructionMember/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
    public RestResult update(@RequestBody ConstructionMember constructionMember) {
        try {
            ConstructionMember source = constructionMemberRepository.findOne(constructionMember.getId());
            ConstructionMember updatedConstructionMember = constructionMemberRepository.save(dtoConverter.fillConstructionMemberForm(source, constructionMember));
            return new RestResult(updatedConstructionMember);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error when updating constructionMember.", e);
            return new RestResult(true, MESSAGE_CANNOT_SAVE);
        }
    }
```

- Here is my Repository

  ```
  public interface ConstructionMemberRepository extends 
  BaseRepository<ConstructionMember, Long> {
  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"constructionTeam","user"})
  Page<ConstructionMember> findById(Long id, Pageable pageable);

  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"constructionTeam","user"})
  Page<ConstructionMember> findAll(Pageable pageable);
  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"constructionTeam","user"})
  List<ConstructionMember> findAll();

  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"constructionTeam","user"})
  ConstructionMember findOne(Long id);
  }
  ```

**- Here is my Modal Mapper.**

```
public ConstructionMember fillConstructionMemberForm(ConstructionMember destination,ConstructionMember form) {
modelMapper.map(form, destination);
return destination;
}
```

Please help me ! .
Thank you all you guys.